# DataFrame.registerTempTable sql failed

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have dataframe in the following schema:

```
df.printSchema()
//root
// |-- FileItem: array (nullable = true)
// |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
// |    |    |-- -created: string (nullable = true)
// |    |    |-- -uid: string (nullable = true)
// |    |    |-- Accessed: string (nullable = true)
// |    |    |-- Changed: string (nullable = true)
// |    |    |-- Created: string (nullable = true)
```

I register table FileItem

```
df.registerTempTable("FileItem")
val newdf = sqlContext.sql("select FileItem.-uid from FileItem")
```

But error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.17] failure: ``*'' expected but `-' found

select FileItem.-uid from FileItem
                ^
```

Is there a way to get the column "-uid"?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should escape the name:

```
sqlContext.sql("select FileItem.`-uid` from FileItem")
```